# Icons are not visible when designing the Flutter project

Tags: flutter, dart

While working in VS Code, Flutter update came and said. As you can see in the picture later, the preview of the icons has become deadlocked.

[image]

Comment: Same thing happend to me yesterday, buy today is ok! I did nothing. Maybe a VS Code restart?

Comment: Problem was solved. Dart update has problem. https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/2333

Comment: wait how was it solved? I still don't see anything and Dart cannot be uninstalled because flutter depends on it. It has auto-updated a bunch of times but the issue persists.

Comment: @fenchai use "flutter upgrade" command

Comment: @CaKaL I am sure I am on the latest flutter and Dart SDK.

Comment: @fenchai Can you say that which version?

Comment: @caKaL sure, Flutter = 1.22.3, dart = 2.10.3

Comment: @fenchai What is the VScode plugin version? Current version is v3.16.0

Comment: @caKaL I haven't checked the version, do you mean the flutter Extension? I'm sure also the latest one as they auto update. or do you mean something else?

Comment: @fenchai yes I meant the flutter extension. v3.9.0 has the problem. No problem in v3.9.1 and later. You can find detailed information on the link I shared above.

Comment: @CaKaL I took a look at my Flutter and Dart Plugin versions in VSCode and it seems both are at 3.16.0